# Zend Select with multiple bound parameters

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I'm trying to write a query using a Zend_Db_Table object with multiple bound parameters. My query, before I put in the real values, was being run as follows:

```
$mytbl = new MyTable();
$myresults = $mytbl->fetchAll(
        "(col1 LIKE 'val1' AND col2 LIKE 'val2') 
        OR (col1 LIKE 'val2' AND col2 LIKE 'val1')) 
        AND col3 = 'val3');
```

This works - except my variables are not being quoted properly. I tried to then replace the second line with:

```
$mytbl->fetchAll(
        "(col1 LIKE ? AND col2 LIKE ?) 
        OR (col1 LIKE ? AND col2 LIKE ?)) 
        AND col3 = ?, 
        array(
            $db->quote($val1), 
            $db->quote($val2), 
            $db->quote($val2), 
            $db->quote($val1), 
            $db->quote($val3)));
```

but then I get an SQL error that the number of parameters does not match. So I tried:

```
$mytbl->fetchAll(
        $mytbl->select()
            ->where("(col1 LIKE ? AND col2 LIKE ?) 
                    OR (col1 LIKE ? AND col2 LIKE ?)) AND col3 = ?, 
                    array(
                        $db->quote($val1), 
                        $db->quote($val2), 
                        $db->quote($val2), 
                        $db->quote($val1), 
                        $db->quote($val3))));
```

but I get the same error. If I put a single parameter, without the array, then it does the replacement properly, but with the array, it does not work. How can I bind multiple parameters like this?

Answer (score 1):

just use IN and put the questionmark in brackets... example:

```
$productIds = array(1, 2, 3);

$select = $db->select()
             ->from('products',
                    array('product_id', 'product_name', 'price'))
             ->where('product_id IN (?)', $productIds);
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to quote your variables, ZF takes care of this for you:

```
$mytbl->fetchAll(
        "(col1 LIKE ? AND col2 LIKE ?) 
        OR (col1 LIKE ? AND col2 LIKE ?)) 
        AND col3 = ?", 
        array($val1, $val2, $val3, $val4, $val5));
```

Comment: that doesn't work - I get an error about invalid number of parameters, even though I've counted to be sure the number is exactly correct.